# Is it possible to have more then one version of NPM installed without NVM?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to have multiple versions of **NPM** installed without **NVM**? If it is, is there any command to view them like the command.

> npm --version

I guess it's possible to have one version NPM for global and a other version for local projects?

As alex mentioned in the comments, NVM is a alternative to make this possible but is it possible without it?

Comment: node version manager

Comment: yeah forgot to mention nvm, is it possible without it?

Comment: I think you can create multiple users in linux for each project and setup `.bashrc` for each of them to point to diff version of node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just install it locally:

```
$ mkdir -p npm2/node_modules
$ cd npm2
$ npm install npm@2
```

Now use your local npm instead global one:

```
$ npm --version
3.10.3
$ ./node_modules/npm/cli.js --version
2.15.11
```